# get amount of last array in php

Tags: php

I am working in codeigniter. I have an array like parent and its child that is display below.

```
Array
(
[id] => 27
[Name] => MUKESH CHUNAWALA
[children] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 160
                [Name] => PRAVINBHAI PARMAR
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 161
                                [Name] => ARATIBEN PRAVINBHAI PARMAR
                                [amnt] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [amnt] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 188
                [Name] => pravinbhai parmar
                [amnt] => 0
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 189
                [Name] => AMRISHBHAI  S. CHUNAWALA
                [amnt] => 0
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 190
                [Name] => DHARMESH RANA
                [amnt] => 0
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => 191
                [Name] => Chadhri Kavita
                [amnt] => 0
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [id] => 192
                [Name] => vasava  Shitalben
                [amnt] => 0
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [id] => 194
                [Name] => SUDHABEN R CHUNAWALA
                [amnt] => 0
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [id] => 195
                [Name] => SAROJBEN R PARMAR
                [amnt] => 0
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [id] => 196
                [Name] => Rabari.Shantilal.B
                [amnt] => 0
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [id] => 197
                [Name] => POOJABHAI.A.BARIYA
                [amnt] => 0
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [id] => 198
                [Name] => LATABEN VASAVA
                [amnt] => 0
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [id] => 199
                [Name] => ARVINDBHAI VASAVA
                [amnt] => 0
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [id] => 200
                [Name] => ROHIT VARSHABEN LALITBHAI
                [amnt] => 0
            )

        [13] => Array
            (
                [id] => 201
                [Name] => CHHATRIVALA HINABEN HARISHBHAI
                [amnt] => 40
            )

        [14] => Array
            (
                [id] => 202
                [Name] => MANISHABEN CHUNAWALA
                [amnt] => 40
            )

        [15] => Array
            (
                [id] => 203
                [Name] => KALPANA J RANA
                [amnt] => 40
            )

        [16] => Array
            (
                [id] => 204
                [Name] => CHUNAWALA SHAILESHKUMAR G
                [amnt] => 40
            )

        [17] => Array
            (
                [id] => 205
                [Name] => Anitaben.b Rajput
                [amnt] => 184
            )

        [18] => Array
            (
                [id] => 206
                [Name] => VASANTBHAI VASAVA
                [amnt] => 184
            )

        [19] => Array
            (
                [id] => 207
                [Name] => vasant.f.vasava
                [amnt] => 328
            )

        [20] => Array
            (
                [id] => 208
                [Name] => SALAT SADIKHUSEN GULAMMAHAMMAD
                [amnt] => 376
            )

        [21] => Array
            (
                [id] => 211
                [Name] => Ranjit B Vasava
                [amnt] => 376
            )

        [22] => Array
            (
                [id] => 212
                [Name] => JIVANBHAI P VAGHELA
                [amnt] => 376
            )

        [23] => Array
            (
                [id] => 214
                [Name] => RAMESHBHAI BARIYA
                [amnt] => 376
            )

        [24] => Array
            (
                [id] => 215
                [Name] => MANSURI SALEEMBHAI RASULBHAI
                [amnt] => 376
            )

        [25] => Array
            (
                [id] => 218
                [Name] => MANSURI SALEEMBHAI RASULBHAI
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 161
                                [Name] => ARATIBEN PRAVINBHAI PARMAR
                                [amnt] => 616
                            )

                    )

                [amnt] => 616
            )

        [26] => Array
            (
                [id] => 219
                [Name] => BHARATBHAI VANKAR
                [amnt] => 616
            )

        [27] => Array
            (
                [id] => 221
                [Name] => MUSTUFAKHAN K PATHAN
                [amnt] => 616
            )
    )

)
```

Now, I want to fetch amount of last id.Here, last id is 27. SO I want to fetch amount of 27 id. So what code should I have to write to get amount of last id?

And I want to get Name from parent array so what code should I have to write?

Comment: you want to achieve this without looping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$last = end($your_array['children']);
$amt = $last['amnt'];
```

Note that `end()` advances array's internal pointer to the last element.

Comment: @Viral I want  to get parent id and Name so what code I have to write?

Comment: If `$your_array` is parent, `$parent_id = $your_array['id'];` and `$parent_name = $your_array['Name'];`

Comment: very neat solution.But some of the experts are not ready to give the solution for the second question or doubt.Asked to raise a new question:( neat @viral